# Lagrangian of a single scalar field

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, lagrangian-formalism, field-theory, variational-calculus

[image]

Hello all,

I've been trying to understand how Sean Carroll is able to come to the conclusion that he does in $1.153$. I tried replacing my dummy index $\sigma$ with $\nu$ based on the substitution that we did on $1.151$  on both the partial derivatives and the metric, yet I am unable to understand how one gets $2\eta ^{\mu \nu }\partial _{\nu }$

Comment: what book is this?

Answer (score 3):

Replace $\sigma \to \nu$ and $\rho \to \nu$. You can do this because both are dummy indices. Then use the symmetry of the metric $\eta^{\nu\mu}=\eta^{\mu\nu}$.